# Memory usage constantly grows on Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, memory

I am developing a game using Java 1.6 alongside with the LWJGL. I have a MacBook Pro and a Windows 8 Desktop Computer and I only code on the MacBook. Today I decided to test my game on my Desktop Computer and something really weird happened. The Task Manager shows a constant growth of memory usage on my app. At some point (around 700MB) the whole computer gets really slow which gets better after I kill my game process. The weird part is that this problem will neither happen on Mac OSX 10.9 nor on Windows 7 (Parallels Virtual Machine on my Mac). As I make use of different OpenGL calls, I have already used Apple's OpenGL Profiler and there seems to be no problem, everything shows up as expected.

I have also tried to analyse my app (on my Windows 8 desktop) using VisualVM which weirdly showed expect results: stable Heap Size and Heap Usage.

What can possibly be happening? How can I 'debug' this?

**Edit:**
I just found out that the same problem happens if I boot into Windows 7 instead of using Parallels Virtual Machine on my MacBook Pro. I think the problem is related to Windows.

**Edit 2:**
I've been testing the code by taking some parts out of it (the game is a big loop at the end of the day) and I noticed that the problem occurs on the most recent part that I've coded: the Lighting System. There is a function which is called every 16ms called tick() inside every system. If I empty the Lighting System's tick() function, the problem goes away. I've tried to remove parts of the tick function to see what happens. This functions works by querying which game entities produce light (and generate shadows) and then actually renders the shadow textures. Everything runs OK until when I start the rendering process, which consists of several shaders passes, each of which looks like this:

'**layer**', '**fbo**', '**distanceShader**' and '**distanceTexture**' are global variables which I reutilize.

```
layer.setTexture(SpriteSheet.teste.getTexture()); //set the texture atlas
layer.setShader(distanceShader); //set the shader
fbo = new Framebuffer(new Vector2f(light.getCurrentRadius() * 2, light.getCurrentRadius() * 2), new Vector3f(1f, 1f, 1f), 0f); //generate a framebuffer object
fbo.init(); //initialize it
fbo.begin(); //begin the rendering step
distanceShader.bind(); //bind the shader
distanceShader.setUniform("transform", transform.getOrthographicTransformation(new Vector2f(position.getPosition().getXInt(), position.getPosition().getYInt()))); //pass info into the shader
distanceShader.setUniformf("lightRadius", light.getCurrentRadius()); //pass info into the shader
distanceShader.setUniformf("ambientLight", ambientLight); //pass info into the shader
render(); //render the 'layer'
fbo.end(); //end the rendering step
distanceTexture = fbo.getTexture(); //keep a reference to the texture generated on the fbo, to which I rendered. it will be used in the next step's layer.setTexture()
fbo.dispose(false); //free fbo's GPU memory (false means it's texture is not being disposed)
```

I do this several times, each step uses the texture generated on the last step, and the possible Memory Leak is happening at those pieces of code. If I leave only the piece I pasted here, I get the memory problem. If I leave more pieces, I get it faster. I should add that every texture (such as 'distanceTexture' is disposed at the end of the tick() function).

Comment: Does it crash if you let the memory grow? What's the version of JVM you are using, maybe try using a different version

Comment: The program does not crash. It went up to 1.1GB of RAM and was marked as 'Not Responding'. My JVM version is the newest one. I installed it today.

Comment: Can you check to see how often the JVM does GC?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: See http://java.dzone.com/articles/tracking-excessive-garbage

Comment: But wouldn't `fbo = new Framebuffer(...)` keep creating new `Framebuffer` and `Vector3f` objects and keep filling up the memory? **Maybe use a factory?** And since the `new Vector3f(1f, 1f, 1f)` is *always* the same, **create it *once* and reuse it.** Similarly for `distanceTexture = fbo.getTexture()` **is the `getTexture()` method guaranteed to reuse objects** it is returning?

Comment: The fbo = new Framebuffer() line surely eats more and more memory, but isn't that the way we a are supposed to do things in Java? Until now, I thought the Garbage Colletor would handle stuff like that. I use 'new' in many different places of the code and it works fine. What do you mean by getTexture() being guaranteed to reuse objects? It does NOT return a new Texture(), it just returns a reference to the Texture contained inside the fbo object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use memory analyser MAT http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to see which objects are taking up the memory.
2. You can use jconsole to see how memory is used and how many times it does GC, you can also force GC to see if it is a GC problem  and forcing a GC will solve your problem. Then it might be just some unused variables not being garbage collected. jconsole now comes as a part of java 7. So you can start it by entering "jconsole &" in your command line.
3. If its fbo object taking up all the space, I would add fbo = null as the last line.